# Make: How to generate list of all .c files except one

Tags: c, makefile, glob

I have a make project with two real targets, a testsuite and the project's executable.

To build these I want rules something like:

```
testsuite: *.c (except executable.c) *.h
    clang ... *.c (except executable.c) -o testsuite

executable: *.c (except testsuite.c) *.h
    clang ... *.c (except testsuite.c) -o executable
```

What's the correct syntax for this, if it's possible?

Comment: Just as an idea; You could put your .c files in a separate directory, excluding the two targets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want.

```
# Explicitly list the sources specific to each target.
EXECUTABLE_SOURCES := executable.c
TESTSUITE_SOURCES := testsuite.c

# Filter out all specific sources from the common wildcard-ed sources.
COMMON_SOURCES := $(filter-out $(TESTSUITE_SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE_SOURCES),$(wildcard *.c))

testsuite: $(TESTSUITE_SOURCES) $(COMMON_SOURCES)
        clang ....

executable: $(EXECUTABLE_SOURCES) $(COMMON_SOURCES)
        clang ....
```

Answer (score 1):

caveat: I did not test

You could use something like `testsuite: $(filter-out executable.c,$(wildcard *.c))` . I think `wildcard` function is needed, as you don't want to operate on string "*.c", but its expansion. Prerequisites are expanded automatically, but function arguments are not. From `info make`:

> Wildcard expansion is performed by 'make' automatically in targets
>   and in prerequisites.  In recipes, the shell is responsible for wildcard
>   expansion.  In other contexts, wildcard expansion happens only if you
>   request it explicitly with the 'wildcard' function.